# Datatables server side processing pagination issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable, pagination

I am trying to make datatables play well with my rest API. Let me just state right of the bat: **"The REST api will not be changed!**.

When using serverside processing, datatables wants to send specific query parameters and expects to get back a specific format. This, to me, is bullocks. Noone wants to modify their backend to match the convention of a third party library (although, I suppose, it is great that there is a default provided).

I have set up my table like so:

```
{
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/api/customers/",
      "dataSrc": "results",
      "data": function (data, settings) {
        // Modify query parameters to match my API
        data.page = ...
        data.page_size = ...
        return data
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

As you can tell, i have used the `ajax.data` property to govern what the table requests from the API. This is great. works like a charm. When the response returns, it looks like this

```
{
    "count": 85,
    "next": "http://myurl.com/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        ...  // The actual data
    ]
}
```

From my configuration, you can tell that I use `ajax.dataSrc` to have the table pick up the `results` property, but I can't find any documentation regarding how to pick up pagination info from my response. I have tried modifying my configuration to

```
{
    ...
    "ajax": {
      "url": "/api/customers/",
      "dataSrc": function(data) {
          return {
              recordsTotal: data.count,
              recordsFiltered: ...,
              data: data.results,
              ...
          }
      },
      ...
    },
    ...
}
```

But that just threw an error. Does not seem to be possible... So then, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - this isn't possible using the `ajax.dataSrc` option. It tells DataTables where to get the data for the rows (`data.results` in your example), but there is no way using `ajax.dataSrc` to tell it where to get the `recordsTotal` etc.

For that you need to use the `ajax` option as a function - make your Ajax call and return an object. Basically similar to what you are doing already, but you call `$.ajax` as well.

Comment: With all the respect due, how about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/32947613/3549014

Comment: Yes - using `ajax.dataSrc` to modify the JSON returned works. Good point!