# Custom data source property dataSrc and pagination issue

Tags: jquery, json, datatables, yii2

I'm working with jQuery DataTables and server-side processing mode. But I'm facing an issue with data table, I've search every thing in Datatables documentation but couldn't find my answer.

So the problem is I'm getting response from server as JSON like this:

[image: JSON response]

As you can see in this JSON response, datatables required JSON is in `data.data` to set this data source in datatables there is a property which is [Custom Data Property](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html) and it working fine and shows the rows. Now problem is that datatables is not considering pagination parameters from JSON which is why it show's this:

[image: Pagination]

Please note that I cannot change JSON response from server side.

**Update:**
Here is js call script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#example").dataTable({
      "ajax": {
          url: app.getApiUrlWithAccessToken('lead/get_all'),
          dataSrc: function(json){
              return json.data.data;
          }
      },
      "lengthMenu": [1,2,5,10,15],
      "columns": [
          { "data": "first_name" },
          { "data": "last_name" },
          { "data": "title" },
          { "data": "email" },
          { "data": "city" },
          { "data": "status" }
      ],
      "processing": true,
      "serverSide": true
   });
});
```

Comment: Seem your request filter the response, show your request and show/explain also the command you can use for a list response

Comment: @scaisEdge i've updated the question.

Comment: which version you are using ?

Comment: datatables expects `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` from server to display the message `showing 0 to 10 of 100 records`. [Docs](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/server-side)

Comment: @JSantosh i'm using DataTables-1.10.9, i've change the iTotalRecords,iTotalDisplayRecords but nothing happens.

Comment: using `console.log(json.data.data)`  log it into console and post the data  in this variable `json.data.data`  here.

Comment: here is the json of `json.data.data` `"[{"first_name":"facebook","last_name":"Anwwar","title":"gjhgjh","email":"Google@google.com","city":"Karachi","status":"pending","user":null}]"`

Comment: In your datatables initialisation code, try changing `$("#example").dataTable({` to `$("#example").DataTable({`.  You're using v1.9 init code, but the returned json is 1.10, so there may be a compatibility issue.

Comment: @markpsmith nopes, it's not working ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### CAUSE

In server-side processing mode DataTables expects [certain structure](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) in returned data. Parameters `draw`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` should be top-level properties. You response has these parameters as sub-properties of `data`, not where DataTables would be looking for them.

#### SOLUTION

Set parameters `draw`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` as top-level properties of JSON response where DataTables expects them to be.

Use the following code for [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc#function) option:

```js
dataSrc: function(json){
   json.draw = json.data.draw;
   json.recordsTotal = json.data.recordsTotal;
   json.recordsFiltered = json.data.recordsFiltered;

   return json.data.data;
}
```

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o5tjdwxk/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @TouqeerShafi, you're right, I've corrected my answer.

Comment: seems the new version is like this dataFilter: function(data){
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
            json.recordsTotal = json.total;
            json.recordsFiltered = json.total;
            json.data = json.list;
 
            return JSON.stringify( json ); // return JSON string
        }