# How to alter ajax responses that will be handled by DataTables in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, datatables

As you might know, ASP.NET gives ajax response with `d` parameter. I tried to alter this with:

```
dataSrc: function (json) {
    return json.d.data;
}
```

But when I run it, it shows `jquery.dataTables.js:4108 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…).` As you can see on the image I attached within this post. I checked in that part and I conclude `dataSrc` doesn't really alter all the response.

[image]

This is what I did for the DataTables's ajax option:

```
dataTable: {
    ajax: {
        type: 'POST',
        url: window.location.href + '/GetData',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        dataSrc: function (json) {
            return json.d.data;
        },
        ..... //other options
}
```

So, is there any other option to alter all the responses that will be handled by DataTables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this in **dataSrc**. This solution based on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941913/custom-data-source-property-datasrc-and-pagination-issue).

```
"dataSrc": function (data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);

    var myData = {};
    myData.draw = parseInt(json.draw);
    myData.recordsTotal = parseInt(json.recordsTotal);
    myData.recordsFiltered = parseInt(json.recordsFiltered);
    myData.data = json.data;

    return myData.data;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome, but it not works for me. Here is the link of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544765/jquery-datatable-pagination-and-filter-not-display-correctly. Can you share your datatable structure there. Thanks.

Comment: Well, it's not fully working yet actually. It shows the data now (previously, it didn't) but for instance, the footer still shows `Showing the NaN to NaN of NaN records`. The same failure like yours.

Comment: Really?? Is it because of datatable issue. Anyway, if you found the solution, please share ya. Anyway thanks.

Comment: Well, I'm still not sure why. Sure thing. I'll will post it to your question if I found something. Please do it for me as well if you don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are not parsing response. First of all make `ajax` call separated and assign that response after parsing to `aaData`(datatable prop).

And make sure you have to specify all column which you want to show in table see `"aoColumns": [{ "mData": "YourColumnName1" }]` in code. Hope this will help you

```
 var ResponseData = CallAjaxMethod(YourUrl, "");//This will make Ajax call and get response
    ResponseData = JSON.parse(ResponseData); //This will pars your response

//'#tblId' this is table id where you want to show your table
$('#tblId').DataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "aaData": ResponseData,//Its your response 
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "YourColumnName1" },
            ....
            { "mData": "YourColumnNamen },

        ]
    });
```