# jQuery Datatable: pagination and filter not display correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, datatables

I dont know how to solve this, try a whole day but didn't success to fix the pagination. I'm using jQuery datatable, and to display my huge data, I'm using server side.

As a testing, only call 10 row of data to the table. Then before pass to table, I restructured the data inside **dataSrc**, using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941913/custom-data-source-property-datasrc-and-pagination-issue) . The table display successfully but the pagination and filter not display correctly.

Can anyone help this.

Below is my code.

**AJAX**

```
$('#example').DataTable({
  "processing": true,
  "serverSide": true,
  "ajax": {
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "datatables.aspx/GetData",
     'data': function (data) {
        return JSON.stringify(data);
     },
     "dataSrc": function (data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);

        var myData = {};
        myData.draw = parseInt(json.otherData[0].draw);
        myData.recordsTotal = parseInt(json.otherData[0].recordsTotal);
        myData.recordsFiltered = parseInt(json.otherData[0].recordsFiltered);
        myData.data = json.searchData;

        return myData.data;
     }
   },
   "columns": [
      { "data": "Username" }
   ]
  }
});
```

**C#**

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false)]
public static string GetData(int draw, object columns, object order, int start, int length, object search)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string mySql = "SELECT TOP 10 username AS Username FROM user_lookup";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mySql, con))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                con.Open();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds, "searchData");

                DataTable newDT = new DataTable("otherData");

                //Add columns to DataTable.
                newDT.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[4] {
                    new DataColumn("draw"),
                    new DataColumn("recordsTotal"),
                    new DataColumn("recordsFiltered"),
                    new DataColumn("userRole")
                });

                //Add rows to DataTable.
                newDT.Rows.Add(draw, length, start, "myrole");
                ds.Tables.Add(newDT);

                string JSONString = string.Empty;
                JSONString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
                return JSONString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the data I return back to datatable to structured the table.
[image]

Data filter and pagination not correct, should be only 1 page of pagination.
[image]

Comment: Please check this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744802/how-do-i-write-linqs-skip1000-take100-in-pure-sql

Comment: @Haksu this has nothing to do with his question.

Comment: because your recordsFiltered = 0 in your response - try changing recordsFiltered = totalRecords see what happens

Comment: Try already before, even you see in the picture I got recordsTotal = 10, at least total of row will shown up instead of NaN. It seem that there is an issue in the plugins.

Comment: @saf21 i have observed two things in your code 1. you are sending `DataSet` with name `(searchData)` as the `Response` but you didn't accessing the exact `DataTable` in the response .

Comment: @Webruster, I return`mydata.data = searchData` in dataSrc. The other data is for others.

Comment: @saf21 right , now see  OtherData is being Stored in DataSet `SearchData` and you need to filter from the  `mydata.data` in order to retrieve the    `myData.recordsFiltered` or other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a solution for our case. You should modify the object of your response directly.

```
"dataSrc": function (data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);

        data.draw = parseInt(json.otherData[0].draw);
        data.recordsTotal = parseInt(json.otherData[0].recordsTotal);
        data.recordsFiltered = parseInt(json.otherData[0].recordsFiltered);
        data.data = json.searchData;

        return data.data;
     }
```

Hopefully, it works in your case.

Comment: @saf21 glad to hear that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your response doesn't contain property `otherData` and `searchData` and you are accessing data by these names.

Your response is a simple object which has following properties.

- `data`
- `recordsTotal`
- `recordsFiltered`
- `draw`

So you need to access them directly from your response like this

```
var myData = {};
myData.draw = parseInt(json.draw);
myData.recordsTotal = parseInt(json.recordsTotal);
myData.recordsFiltered = parseInt(json.recordsFiltered);
myData.data = json.data;
```

Also `recordsTotal` is should be `total` number of `records` right now you are returning `10` and records shown are also `10`.

You are getting `NaN` because there is no property `json.otherData[0].recordsFiltered` so when you will change it to `json.recordsFiltered` it will show `numbers`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but I already do like you suggest. You can check in the the code above. I found out the return data in dataSrc only for draw the table, not draw the filter and pagination.

Comment: Can you make a js fiddle ?