# DataTables server-side pagination

Tags: java, spring, datatables

I have working Spring REST app with client side pagination, default by DataTables and everything works. Now i need to change it to server-side pagination i have problem, because have no idea how to get information from DataTables what page number client want to see. I can't find anything usefull in DT manual.

Answer (score 31):

When you say `Datatable` I assume you are talking about [**DataTables**](https://datatables.net/) jQuery plugin.

To activate serverside pagination you need to pass

```
"serverSide": true,
```

like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/your_url"
});
```

Doing the above will activate your server-side pagination. But you need to do few changes on the server-side too. Let's see them step by step.

### 1. What happens when you mark `serverSide` as `true`

DataTables plugin adds custom parameters to the AJAX call with information like

```
order:  asc
start:  20
length: 10

// and many more.
```

You can inspect this [demo link](https://profile.ashishontech.xyz/datatable) and see the parameters passed in **request** when you click the next page button.

### 2. Similarly, DataTables plugin expects some fields in response in order to preserve *pagination* logic.

```
"draw": 3,             // unique ID
"recordsTotal": 57,    // total number of records
"recordsFiltered": 57  // total number of filtered records
```

You can inspect [this demo link](https://profile.ashishontech.xyz/datatable) and see **response** data this time.

### 3. Now changes are on serverside in your API

You need to add these parameters as `queryParam` for GET and attr in POST call in your controller API:

```
order: asc
start: 20
length: 10
```

### 4. Service Layer Changes - DB query

In-Service Layer where you get details from a database.

You need to get the total number of records and in search query pass a LIMIT clause `LIMIT 10, 10` in case of MySQL.

E.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 20,10;
```

Use `start` and `length` to calculate the next set of records.

It can be trickier but if you understand and implement properly it's fun.

Read more in detail [here](https://ashishontech.xyz/server-side-pagination-jquery-datatable/) which also contains code and live demo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for good answer, but not everything is clear for me. Can you please tell me how can i get information about start and length? I can see in the example only changing draw number, but where are the information about start and length? Sorry if question is trivial...

Comment: I have used the same example and I can see start and length info there. it is available in last . I had to scroll down to last to see start: 10
length: 10
search[value]: 
search[regex]: false

Comment: @MyTwoCents Thank you for the answer but can you please tell me what should I need to do if the backend response which I am getting does not have the same key as "recordsTotal", "recordsFiltered", "draw" instead in the response the key name is different ? 
Can we configure this thing in datatable manually ? Please Help

Comment: @Amara  refer this .. you cant set custom fields but assign fields with custom value like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941913/custom-data-source-property-datasrc-and-pagination-issue

Comment: Excellent answer. This was very confusing for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Please see the sample about DataTables server-side processing:
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

After change page, you can capture the request to server as following format:
https://.../server_processing.php?**draw=3**&columns...&**order=0&dir=asc&start=20&length=10**&search%5Bvalue%5D=&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_=1534436781912

That means DataTable requests page number 3 (draw=3), order by first column ascending, ....

At server side (REST), you can get page number by (for example) request.getParameter("draw")