# couldn't load the data to the datatable using server side pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, pagination

I have tried to implement the  server side pagination concept for my table (jQuery(v1.12.4),datatable(v1.10.15))

As per the datatable server side pagination documentation

I have enabled **serverSide**, **paging**, **processing** as true and specified the **sPaginationType** along with the ajax.

In the [Custom Data Source Property article](https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html), it is mentioned that we need to use dataSrc Option being used as a string to get the data from a different source property, in this case demo but it could be any value, included a nested property by using standard dotted Javascript object notation.

I have used the dataSrc as per the above point ie., **"dataSrc": "data"** based on my json response.

However the data is not being loaded.

**My table loads only the approve button (which i have defined in the columns section) rest of the columns are empty.** - convening that the data are not rendered in the table.

***[Refer Output 2 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hS8A.png)***.

Since I have used **deferLoading** first page returns empty data. Refer Output 1 image.

I have referred all the below mentioned articles

[Custom data source property dataSrc and pagination issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32941913/custom-data-source-property-datasrc-and-pagination-issue)

[Datatables server side processing pagination issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761135/datatables-server-side-processing-pagination-issue)

The code is snippet is shown below, please help

```
$('#vschildtable').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "processing": "Please
            wait - LOADING SCAN Result...", "
            emptyTable " : "
            Currently no
            data found in this project " }, "
            bJQueryUI " : true, "
            paging " :
            true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "processing ": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "columns": [{
                    "defaultContent": "",
                    "visible": false
                }, {
                    "defaultContent": "",
                    "visible": false
                }, {
                    "defaultContent": ""
                }, {
                    "defaultContent": ""
                }, {
                    "defaultContent": ""
                }, {
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: ' <
                        button type = "button"
                    class = "btn-approve label label-link bg-green " > Approve < /button>
                    ' } ], "deferLoading" : 57, "ajax" : { "url" : "emppage?empID=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(empID) + "&projectId=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(projectID) + "&subProjectId=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(subProjectID) + "&pageNo=" +
                    encodeURIComponent(offset),
                    type: 'POST',
                    datatype: "jsonp",
                    "dataSrc": "data"
                }
            });
```

Json response:

```
    [{
   "message":"SUCCESS",
   "data":"{\"data\":\[{\"projectId\":1,\"subProjectId\":1,\"empID\":765,\"empName\":\"Arjun\",\"empIDVersion\":\"1%3A4.1.4\",\"fkempID\":7781,\"tmpempID\":354999,\"noOfDept\":1,\"rowNo\":1,\"totalnoOfDept\":1},{\"projectId\":1,\"subProjectId\":1,\"empID\":765,\"empName\":\"Arjun\",\"empIDVersion\":\"4.0.18.1\",\"fkempID\":7781,\"tmpempID\":355000,\"noOfDept\":1,\"rowNo\":2,\"totalnoOfDept\":1},{\"projectId\":1,\"subProjectId\":1,\"empID\":765,\"empName\":\"Arjun\",\"empIDVersion\":\"4.2.1\",\"fkempID\":7781,\"tmpempID\":355001,\"noOfDept\":1,\"rowNo\":3,\"totalnoOfDept\":1}\]}"
}]
```

Comment: What are the errors? The server code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there's missing information in the data returned by the server. DataTables expects some specific data (`draw`,`recordsFiltered`,etc.) from the server when running in server side mode. You can check [here](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

Furthermore, You should add the `data` property to each object in the `columns` array, specifying the name of the data you expect to render in that column, i.e.:

```
columns:[
    { data:'projectId'   }
    { data:'subPorjectId'}
    ...
]
```

this tells DataTables what data to show in which column.

Hope it helps!